# How to add path in wp_get_archives()?

Tags: wordpress

I can not find where to change path for `wp_get_archives()`...Now i have path `http://example.com/2015`  but i want to add history before 2015 so that i have url:
`http//example.com/history/2015`. Any suggestion?

```
<?php wp_get_archives('type=yearly'); ?>



add_filter( 'get_archives_link', function( $html ) 
{
    if( is_admin() ) // Just in case, don't run on admin side
        return $html;

    // $html is '<li><a href='http://example.com/hello-world'>Hello world!</a></li>'
    $html = str_replace( 'href="http://example.com', 'href="http://example.org', $html );
    return $html;
});
```

I found this but when nothing happend when i added